# USB media that can be safely unplugged while being written to

Tags: linux, usb-storage, filesystem-corruption

I did several tests with unplugging USB media while they are being written to. Host system is Linux Mint 17.1 on a Laptop with USB 2.0. For USB hard disks, it appears that after calling 'sync', data is safely written and will not be corrupted in any way, at least when using EXT4 with the `data=journal` option. This is fine for me, my scripts write to a temporary directory first, then call 'sync', then rename the directory to its final name (which should be an atomic operation).

However, my tests with a USB stick were less convincing. Using the exact same scripts and mount options, I ran into corruptions all the time. More specifically: I use 'rsync' with the `--link-dest` option for backups to the USB medium. What I describe as "corruption" includes files in a backup where the data differs from the file on the host system, but the modification time does not. This is a nasty thing since `rsync` will consider those files up-to-date, when in fact they are outdated or full of null bytes, etc.

**Question:** Why does this happen with USB flash drives and not with hard disks? Or was I just lucky with the hard disks so far? Would it make sense to buy a flash drive from another manufacturer? The one I used for testing here incidentally stopped working for good yesterday after I hot-unplugged it. So maybe it was just a poor-quality product.

Comment: Maybe you can repeat your test with an USB that is not going to stop working, maybe it was not a poor-quality product but only a just defective one... To complete your test I suppose you should test with same (huge) files and same operating system. BTW it can be harmful to _hot unplug_ an __HDD__ that should require the heads to park to avoid damaging.

Comment: Thanks, I have ordered a new flash drive today. About head parking: I have found contradicting information on this. Some say that all or most modern drives will manage to park their heads when power is cut. Maybe someone could comment on this?

Comment: You're welcome.(Let's we hope that)What is written here today can be read again after some years and from people with different level of knowledge; so better to be careful. BTW __I never seen suggested anywhere to _cut the power_ to a device with moving parts meanwhile it is writing__. Meanwhile in an USB pen can cause relative few damages (corruption of the _filesystem_ patchable with normal operation),for sure it can cause loss of data or even worst its corruption, instead in a device with moving parts can generate an [irreversible hardware failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_crash).

Comment: More about heads parking(few): take some moments to read on internet, maybe [start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_failure#Landing_zones_and_load.2Funload_technology). Old _HDD_ were supposed to be used only in desktop and moved really rarely. If I correctly remember, there was a specific command to physically  `park` the head. Note not the head__s__. Nowadays the parking is made moving the head on _landing zone_  where no data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

After testing with the new flash drive, it very much appears that all the trouble came from the previous flash drive being broken or low-quality. With the new flash drive and also the HDDs, I was unable to produce any corruption by unplugging the drive while it is being written to. I even relaxed the mount options by omitting `data=journal`. My mount options are now in total `rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro` and I am using EXT4.

About other filesystems, based on my experience with Linux Mint 17.1: XFS behaves badly when hot-unplugged, often leaving a non-removable mount that requires a re-boot. JFS is ok in this regard, but amazingly slow, almost unusable for certain operations. BTRFS looks good, but Mint comes with an outdated and still unstable version, so I decided against it. Likewise, NILFS2 and F2FS are not well supported on Mint at this time.

A word of warning: although I could not create any corruption by hot-unplugging, it is still the user's responsibility to flush buffers before putting a file in its final location. So, a backup program must first copy to a temporary location, then call `sync`, and then rename the file or directory to its final name (under which a complete copy will be expected in the future).